# Create back button to previous state for SPA based with AJAX in MVC ASP.net

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, single-page-application

already I begun Switch ASP.net Web to SPA for use in PWA and all Partial Views call with AJAX only. but now I have a problem, I wanna set a back button like IOS for back to previous Partial View. I want to know if I have the ability to identify the history of my previous AJAX calls and link to them ?